# Django & Nginx issue with "www" and non-"www" URL

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx

I have a problem understanding how to run my Django app with Nginx (server is Ubuntu).

So, I have a site which allows for user accounts, and it currently has a problem, where both "www" and non-"www" URLs load. This is problematic, because logging-in to one, will not reflect to the other. Besides that, it's also confusing. I want to keep the non-"www" variant.

I followed the instructions here on how to do it using Ngnix:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-redirect-www-to-non-www-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

And it worked when I tried to load the domain. But when I started the Django app, it stopped working.

I'm really confused on how to get it working, is there some way of running my django app through Nginx?

Thanks!

EDIT: I've included the server config thing (I think)

default

```
server {
    server_name www.nilly.com;
    return 301 $scheme://nilly.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your current configuration... we can't really help without seeing what you have tried so far.

Comment: Apologies, I'm extremely newb when it comes to these things. How do I show you my current config?

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38987907/edit) your question to include your nginx configuration.

Comment: Thanks @solarissmoke , I found it and have edited it into the question.

Comment: There is no Django app configured in the server config you posted. Also, do you get any error messages (likely in `/var/log/nginx/error_log` or similar)

Comment: Yes, when I restart Ngnix, and load the site, it says something to the effect of "Welcome to Ngnix!". I'd like to note that when Ngnix is running, it successfully redirects to the non-"www" URL. Anyway, I tried running my Django app using "python manage,py runserver nilly,com:80", but it says that port 80 was in use. So then I have to kill that with "sudo fuser -k 80/tcp" in order to make it work. I guess that takes down Ngnix. So, I know that I have to put in commands into that file, but I don't know how or where.

Comment: Concerning the error in the log file, it says "[emerg] 17346#17346: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)" several times.

Comment: Yip, that will happen because Nginx is listening on that port. You need a gateway interface like uWSGI or Gunicorn to serve your Django app. Nginx will act as a reverse proxy. Check out [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-14-04) link for a tutorial on deployment with Gunicorn.

Comment: Thank you! Server stuff is really complex. Appreciate it, and thank you to @solarissmoke as well!